# App with most logic on the serverside (web api design)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a mobile application that allows managers in companies to record when employees fall ill and contact them at certain points after their sick leave has started (so they know the status of the employee).

The app is pretty dumb. It relies heavily on a web api. From the web api, the app gets info about who to contact when. The app is also able to register that an employee has fallen ill, that an ill employee is no longer ill and that a manager has contacted an employee. All the logic for these actions is located in the web api.

There are two classes, `Employee` and `SickLeave`. `Employee` contains name and phonenumber of an actual employee. `SickLeave` contains two employees (1 ill, 1 manager) and a boolean to determine if it is still active.

With all the logic residing in the web api, all the `POST` requests (creating, changing sick leave entries) are super simple. Basically all the web api needs to know is the action to be performed and the relevant id's involved. So I end up with:

`POST` request to `api/sickleave/new` containing the id of the employee and the id of the manager.

`POST` request to `api/register/healthy` containing the id of the sickleave.

`POST` request to `api/register/contact` containing the id of the sickleave.

etc.

This is confusingly simple and leads me to believe that I'm doing something wrong? It can't be right, that all a `POST` request contains is an id?

Answer (score 0):

According to the design principles of REST, a POST should be used when creating a new entity. PUT is for updating an entire entity and PATCH is for partially updating an entity.

Generally speaking, your API structure should be based on the structure of your entities so you should have /api/sickleave/ and /api/employee/. I see from your example that you have not really followed this pattern, instead you have API actions for different statuses. This means your API is not fully RESTful.

If you were to fully implement a REST structure, to record a new sick leave, you can POST to /api/sickleave/ with the ID of the employee (as you are already doing). I think it is fine if the API figures out the manager ID internally.

To update the status of the sickleave, you should PUT or PATCH to /api/sickleave/{id}/ modifying the relevant details. You should also delete sick leave by sending a DELETE request to /api/sickleave/{id}.

REST is just a pattern and you can really overcomplicate things by strictly following every minute detail of the pattern. However on the flip-side, not following patterns and best practices makes your code hard to understand for other developers.

Hope this helps. I'd probably need to see your full data structure to give you lower level details.